# $window.scrollTo specific section of a page after a $location.path redirect in angular

Tags: angularjs, angular, redirect, scroll

This link in the menu brings me to the dashboard. If I am on the dashboard and I click the link. The window scrolls to the section of the page I need it to go to. However, if I am on another page and I click this link it redirects but does not scroll to the specific section of the page. What can I do to get it to scroll when I am coming from another page other than the dashboard?

```
<li><a href ng-click="scrollToSection()" highlight=".content"><i class="fa fa-bell"></i>Click here</a></li>

    $scope.scrollToSection = function(){
            redirectServices.goToPage();
            $window.scrollTo(0, 800); 
        }
```

Comment: Can you post more code on how the redirection is happening ? is it in same ctrl or different ?

Comment: Can you use debugger ? please mention code is going through function in both scenario.

Comment: @sam_dev separate ctrl                                                     
 this. goToPage =function(){
  $location.path('/dashboard');
 }

Comment: The code above is just redirecting, you need a call the scrollToSection() too. There are multiple ways you can solve it one way is have service which sets the scroll position when you click from other controller and in this ctrl get the property and then scroll to .